# Linq Concat optimisation

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently attempting to pull results from three different tables and merge them into one list like so...

```
var accountLogs = Context.AccountLogs.Where(s => s.Timestamp > fromDate).Select(s => new LogSummaryDto()
{
    UserId = s.User.Id,
    DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
});

var spellLogs = Context.SpellLog.Where(s => s.Timestamp > fromDate).Select(s => new LogSummaryDto()
{
    UserId = s.User.Id,
    DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
});
var generalLogs = Context.Log.Where(s => s.Timestamp > fromDate).Select(s => new LogSummaryDto()
{
    UserId = s.User.Id,
    DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
}); 

var m1 = accountLog.Concat(spellLogs);
var m2 = m1.Concat(generalLogs).toList();
```

However, I'm sure there must be some way using linq to do this is one query, any ideas/pointers?

Comment: If that query returns the correct result it's fine, due to LINQ's deferred execution you only execute a single query here. Actually you are not even executing it in your code. Use a `foreach` or create a collection with `m1.Concat(generalLogs).ToList();`. Then the query will be executed.

Comment: @ChrisF You can do it even better: `m1 = accountLog.Concat(spellLog).Concat(generalLogs)`, without usage of `m2`! :) Just kidding

Comment: What about creating a view in database and concat all results together with `UNION ALL`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter has answered this, the fastest solution so far is what it already is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Concat` early, and filter all at once, like this:

```
var res = Context.AccountLogs.Select(s => new {
        s.TimeStamp
    ,   s.User.Id
    ,   s.User.DisplayName
    }).Concat(Context.SpellLog.Select(s => new {
        s.TimeStamp
    ,   s.User.Id
    ,   s.User.DisplayName
    })).Concat(Context.Log.Select(s => new {
        s.TimeStamp
    ,   s.User.Id
    ,   s.User.DisplayName
    }))
    // Selects / Concats above provide uniform structure
    // on which to apply the common Where clause
    .Where(s => s.TimeStamp > fromDate)
    .Select(s => new LogSummaryDto() {
        UserId = s.User.Id
    ,   DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
    });
```

Comment: Will this be more efficient than OP's approach? Because it's less reradable and debuggable

Comment: @TimSchmelter This approach is more maintainable, because the `where` clause is not repeated. The `Select` is repeated in the same way as in the original, but it's hard to fix in the absence of a common base type. As far as the efficiency goes, I suspect it's going to be roughly the same, because the number of round-trips is not going to change.

Comment: I'll give both a going over and see what the difference is, @TimSchmelter granted deferred execution waits until its pulled with .toList() ect however sometime the manor in which the query is written can effect processing time, as I found out with .GroupBy the other day. This is however a lot simpler than what I was doing the other day and I may just be over thinking it now.

Comment: I don't find it more maintainable because the filter- conditions could be different in future. Then it's easy with OP's approach but difficult with yours. OP's approach also enables to provide a table-based order easily, so concat each table's results instead of merging them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Given the scenario of searching all logs for a certain activity I find it very unlikely for the `where` clauses to diverge on purpose (as opposed to somebody forgetting to modify one or two of them). I would put all three logs in one table, though, and avoid concatenation altogether, at the cost of small denormalization.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: that's what also came into my mind, OP should use a single table with another column `LogType`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter keeping it separate is the faster method, the where clause kicks in after all the other tables data has loaded slowing everything down rather than being applied from the start.

Comment: @ScottAlexander I changed the structure that should allow the common `Where` clause to be applied in RDBMS. This should be faster than selecting `DTO`s in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract your LINQ logic into your own "LINQ operator". This requires `Context.AccountLogs`, `Context.SpellLog`, `Context.Log` to all implement the same interface. Let's say they all implement `ILog`, e.g.:

```
public interface ILog {
    User User { get; }
    DateTime Timestamp { get; }
}
```

You could then implement your own `ExtractSummaryDtos` like this:

```
public static class LogSummaryDtoExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<LogSummaryDto> ExtractSummaryDtos(this IEnumerable<ILog> logs, DateTime fromDate) {
        return logs.Where(s => s.Timestamp > fromDate).Select(s => new LogSummaryDto {
            UserId = s.User.Id,
            DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can build your list like this:

```
var m3 = AccountLogs.ExtractSummaryDtos(fromDate)
            .Concat(SpellLogs.ExtractSummaryDtos(fromDate))
            .Concat(Logs.ExtractSummaryDtos(fromDate));
```

Comment: This just over complicates it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var m2 = new List<IEnumerable<dynamic>> {AccountLogs, SpellLogs, Logs}
    .SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.Timestamp > fromDate).Select(s => new LogSummaryDto {
        UserId = s.User.Id,
        DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
    }));
```

Comment: I like this because its clean however it suffers the same as other solution, the concats occur before the where so all the data is pulled before the timestamp filtering is applied.

Comment: There seems to be a trade off between performance and concise code, this answer being concise, many other being more performant.

Comment: @ScottAlexander updated to use SelectMany. This should filter before concatenating.

Answer (score -1):

You can use union:

```
var logs = ((
from s in Context.AccountLogs
where s.TimeStamp > fromDate 
select new {
UserId = s.User.Id,
DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
})
.Union(
from s in Context.SpellLog
where s.TimeStamp > fromDate
select new {
UserId = s.User.Id,
DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
})
.Union(
from s in Context.Log
where s.TimeStamp > fromDate
select new
{
UserId = s.User.Id,
DisplayName = s.User.DisplayName
})).ToList();
```